# Add latency when accessing certain websites under linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I've been playing with `tc` on my local machine. `sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 2000ms` adds a 2-second latency to all traffic going through `eth0`.

What I want is to be able to limit this latency to certain websites. I've tried playing with filters on specific IP addresses (Google's, for instance) but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how I can do this using `tc`? Is it the best tool for the job?

Answer (score 2):

You can mark packets with iptables in the mangle table and assign a class id to shape with tc.

The [lartc.org site](http://lartc.org/) has very detailed informations on how to do it (and much more).

Comment: You should also be able to use the u32 classifier to tc filter instead of iptables.